# In a given list, how to determine the small number that followed a bigger number? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, you are given a list say:
`a = [14, 26, 30, 15, 25, 30]`

The small number preceded by a bigger number is 15. So I would want to print the number 15 only.

Here's where I'm at:

```
def alist(a):
    for i in a:
        if i ???
```

Help, I'm lost.

Comment: Why the number is 15 and not 14? (14<26 ans it is < 15)

Comment: What if `a = [14, 26, 30, 15, 25, 9]`? Should it only print 15? Or also 9, as it's smaller then 25. What if `a = [14, 26, 30, 15, 13, 9]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you store the last number for each item in the loop, you can look back to check it.

Start by storing the first number from the list. Loop over the numbers after that (use python array slicing `a[1:]`).

If the current number is less than `<` the last number, then print it.

Always store the current number in the last number.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loops will be much slower, better use `NumPy`, as:

```
import numpy as np
a = [14, 26, 30, 15, 25, 30]
a = np.array(a)
greater_num = a[np.append(False, (a[1:]-a[:-1])<0)]
print(greater_num)

# Output: array([15])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this, without using for loop  -

```
a = [14, 26, 30, 15, 25, 30]
s = set(a) # This is required if you have duplicate elements in your list, will convert list into sets and remove duplicates
print (sorted(s)[1]) # print the second smallest number.
```

Oputput: `15`

You can also use [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/heapq.html)

```
import heapq
a = [14, 26, 30, 15, 25, 30]
print (heapq.nsmallest(2, a)[-1]) # print the second smallest number.
```

Oputput: `15`